# Webview - Can´t see camera option inside gallery for upload

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I´m trying to upload files webpage using html input file all this in a webview, but when i press the button, the gallery opens and i can´t see the camera option, i can only select files.
The version of android i´m using is 7.7 and 8 oreo.

permissions from manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Code from mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 0;
    private WebView myWebView;
    public String mGeolocalizationRequestOrigin = null;
    public GeolocationPermissions.Callback mGeolocalizationCallback = null;

    // UPLOAD ====================================================
    private WebView webView;
    public Uri imageUri;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private  String mCM = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM = null;
    private  ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR = 1;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {
                    if (mUMA == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data)
            if (results != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                mUMA = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            //myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            private Activity activity = null;

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
                if(url.contains("dominio.com.br")) return false;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                           final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                mGeolocalizationRequestOrigin = null;
                mGeolocalizationCallback = null;

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage(R.string.app_name).setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInteraface, int i) {
                                mGeolocalizationRequestOrigin = origin;
                                mGeolocalizationCallback = callback;
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        }).show();
                    } else {
                        mGeolocalizationRequestOrigin = origin;
                        mGeolocalizationCallback = callback;
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    }
                } else {
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
                }
            }

            // UPLOAD ====================================================

            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }

            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
            }

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                //Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
            // ====================================================

        });

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //Habilitando o JavaScript

        // UPLOAD ====================================================
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        // ====================================================

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://dominio.com.br/");
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me on this please?